# How to set max 9 days after datepicker 1 selected by Daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, momentjs, daterangepicker

Hi i want to set default maxDate 9 days after I select input first.
here is my code
HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Date" name="daterange" class="form-control date-picker form-date" id="date-picker" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Date" name="daterange" class="form-control date-picker-2 form-date" id="date date-picker-2"/>
```

and JS

```
  $('.date-picker').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minDate: moment().subtract(1, 'years'),
    maxDate: moment().subtract(1, 'days'),
    locale: {
      format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
    }
  }
var departpicker = $('.date-picker').val();
$('.date-picker-2').daterangepicker({
  minDate: departpicker,
  //here is the bug
  maxDate: moment().add(9, 'days')
});
```

In my mind is how to `departpicker` + 9 days. I try `departpicker.add(9, 'days')` doesnt work. Any body help? For example when I select 1 July 2018 on first input and maxDate on second input is 10 July 2018
my full code https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/Lmjv9hp2/7/
Thank you

Comment: Are you facing it in some specific browser? Your code works fine for me on Chrome  68.0.3440.106.

Comment: not specific browser. for example when I choose 1 July 2018, max Date is 10 July 2018. But that I created is +9 days from date now. @PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the date format before adding 9 days.

```
$('.date-picker-2').daterangepicker({
  minDate: departpicker,
  //here is the bug
  maxDate: moment(departpicker, 'DD-MM-YYYY').add(9, 'days');
});
```

Comment: perfect.. I have specify first. Thanks for the answer @deerawan

Comment: sama-sama bro @dediwibisono :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use  the maxSpan option

```
"maxSpan": {
    "days": 9
},
```

Comment: this option saved me, it is what I was looking for